# What's 'Custom' in chrome's Customize fonts setting?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, fonts

When I look into chrome's settings > Appearance > Customize fonts, I see that "Custom" is selected under "Standard font", "Serif font" and "Sans-serif font". What does it mean? How do I find out which font exactly will be used?

My OS is ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Just click on "Customize fonts" and you can set the default fonts for
Standard font, Serif font, Sans-serif font and Fixed-width font.

You may also set the global size and minimal size for all fonts.